# Relocating html elements with jquery

Tags: jquery, height, this

Could someone help me with this code? I'm trying to rearrange figures in a certain div into two columns (a and b) in such a way the two columns are about the same height. I've got insane trying to find the problem in my code and not finding it. It doesn't work for a reason...

```
<body onload="rearrangeImages();">
   <div class="images"><!-- more than one might exist, each with its own figures -->
      <figure>
         <figcaption>This is the figcaption of this figure. An image is missing for this test.</figcaption>
      </figure>
      <figure>
         <figcaption>This is the figcaption of this figure.</figcaption>
      </figure>
      <figure>
         <figcaption>Another one.</figcaption>
      </figure>
   </div>
   <script>
      function rearrangeImages() {
         $('.images').each(function() {//should work for each .images independently
            $(this).prepend('<div class="column_b"></div>');
            $(this).prepend('<div class="column_a"></div>');
            $(this).append('<div class="test_div"></div>');
            $('figure', this).each(function() {
               var height_a = $(this).parent().$(".column_a").height();
               var height_b = $(this).parent().$(".column_b").height();
               if (height_a > height_b) {
                  $(this).parent().$(".column_b").append(this);
               } else {                        
                  $(this).parent().$(".column_a").append(this);
               }
               $(this).remove();
            });
         });
      }
   </script>
</body>
```

**EDIT**
I have found out myself I should use this selector for height a and b:

```
var height_a = $(this).parent().children(".column_a").height();
```

This is my new jquery:

```
function rearrangeImages() {
   $('.images').each(function() {
      $(this).prepend('<div class="test_div"></div>');
      $(this).prepend('<div class="column_b"></div>');
      $(this).prepend('<div class="column_a"></div>');
      $('figure', this).each(function() {
         var height_a = $(this).parent().children(".column_a").height();
         var height_b = $(this).parent().children(".column_b").height();
         if (height_a > height_b) {
            $(this).parent().children(".column_b").append(this);
         } else {                        
            $(this).parent().children(".column_a").append(this);
         }
      });
   });
}
```

Now I want to extend this function. Pseudocode:

```
if (this is the last figure in .images) {
   //place last figure in test_div to measure its height;
   if (height_a > height_b + height_of_last_image) {
      $(this).parent().children(".column_b").append(this);
   } else {
      $(this).parent().append(this);
   }
} else {
   //do the normal stuff see higher
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The column div's a & b you are prepending to the div images which means they are childern of that div not parents.

If you change your selecotors when appending the figures from this

```
$(this).parent().$(".column_b").append(this);
```

To this, it will find the div's and start working

```
$(".column_b").append(this);
```

One more problem is that you are removing the figure element after you are appending it to another div. Appending removes the elment from it's current container and puts it in the new div so you do not need to remove it.

**Edit** I added in the if block to check the last image based on your pseudo code.
For it to work  i created a counter to keep track of how many time we iterate through the loop.

```
var counter = 1;
```

Your if block inside the figures loop

```
if(counter == $(figures).length ){
```

Also i changed the figures loop to only get the children figures of the current images div.

```
var figures = $(this).children("figure");
$(figures).each(function() {
```

And instead of using

```
$(this).parent().children(".column_a")
```

You can use jquery's sibling() function like so

```
$(this).siblings(".column_a")
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/matt9388/3qbE6/2/) example and below is the code.

```
$(function(){
$('.images').each(function() {
      $(this).prepend('<div class="test_div"></div>');
      $(this).prepend('<div class="column_b"></div>');
      $(this).prepend('<div class="column_a"></div>');
      var counter = 1;
      var figures = $(this).children("figure");
      $(figures).each(function() {
       if(counter == $(figures).length ){
           if (height_a > height_b + $(this).height()) 
           {
               $(this).siblings(".column_b").append(this);
           } 
           else 
           {
              $(this).parent().append(this);
           }
        } 
        else 
        {
            var height_a = $(this).siblings(".column_a").height();
            var height_b = $(this).siblings(".column_b").height();
            if (height_a > height_b) 
            {
                $(this).siblings(".column_b").append(this);
            } 
            else 
            {                        
                $(this).siblings(".column_a").append(this);
            }
         }
         counter++;
      });
   });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I have learned the append() method also removes it from it's curent container. Only for assigning height_a and height_b I reasoned like: 'this' is the figure, so its parent is div.images and in there I search for .column_a; with you just declaring $('.column_a') it finds **every** .column_a, where I only want to find the column_a in this div.images. The reason is, I want more than one such div.images each with different figures to be arranged.

Comment: I have found I should use .children(".column_a"). Now please my edit in the main question to answer how I could extend the function.

Comment: I updated my post with your extended pseudo code. Hope that's what you were looking for.